# Regex Syntax in sql script

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

I wanted to use **two** Regex in a SQL script to retrieve some information in the software. Here are Regex commands:

```
{TRIGGER(63f02a37-1f92-4e36-af2a- 
0e9764b22c75|LastTrigger|Mail.Result.Mail.BodyText)|(?<=Exit No:\s)[0-9]    
{9}}

{TRIGGER(63f02a37-1f92-4e36-af2a- 
0e9764b22c75|LastTrigger|Mail.Result.Mail.BodyText)|(?<=Barcode:\s)[A-Z] 
{9}[0-9]{10}}
```

These regex should be subsituded with **919500006** and '**Barcode**'. Thank you Guys

Here is My SQL Script:

```
 IF ((SELECT ExitPermissionNo FROM tbl_ExitPermission WHERE 
(ExitPermissionNo = '919500006') AND (ReferenceCCS IS NULL))!=1)
BEGIN
UPDATE tbl_ExitPermission
SET ReferenceCCS = 'Barcode'
WHERE ExitPermissionNo = 919500006;
PRINT 'The ReferenceCCS Update Successfully!'
END
ELSE BEGIN
PRINT 'The ExitPermission Not Found!'
RAISERROR('The ExitPermission Not Found!',18,1)
END
```

Comment: SQL Server does not support regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you can do so using:

```
ReferenceCCS\s*=\s*'([^']*)'
```

or:

```
ReferenceCCS\s*=\s*["']([^'"]*)["']
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/JVv3O4/1/)

for the first one, and:

```
(ExitPermissionNo\s*=\s*['"]?)(\d+)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/BtFJE0/1/)

for the second one.

Comment: Thank you emma. I am using VisualCron to automate a sql script. The above two Regex code is reading some info from an incoming email and assign the matched variables to above SQL script and then run that. My question is that How can I use the above two regex codes in SQL Script ?